# Hyperlink all cells from Sheet 1 to same cells from Sheet 2

Tags: excel

Can I hyperlink all cells from Sheet1 to the same cells from Sheet2?

I mean, if I press on cell C1 from Sheet1 to redirect me to cell C1 from sheet2 and so on.

I have like 8000 cells and do it manually will take me years so I'm wondering if there is a faster way to achieve this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use macro:

```
Sub makelinks()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Selection
        If Len(c.value) > 3 Then ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=c, _
        Address:="", SubAddress:="Sheet2!" & c.Address
        Next
End Sub
```

Select the cells you want to be linked and run the macro (Alt-F8). The code should be pasted in Module1 in your visual basic viewer (Alt-F11).

The `If Len(c.value) > 3` is something that's been handy for me, it can be removed if it does not fit your purpose, it just ignores certain cells that has less than 3 characters

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! That's exactly how I wanted it to be! Thank you again!